# Find Wordpress root directory in bash without WP-CLI

Tags: command-line

How can I find the WordPress root directory in Bash without using WP-CLI?

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why WP CLI is specifically excluded in the question? Also, the WP root directory doesn't make sense as a term once you start doing subdirectory installs such as those `composer` would install

Comment: Sure Tom. My current install uses Docker. There's no MySQL server running in my MacOS and `wp` does nothing without MySQL running. I could `ssh` into the docker container and use `wp` there, but that would only give me paths inside the docker container; for BackstopJS to work in my instance I needed various paths on the host machine and not the Docker paths. Ditto for rsync'ing plugins between local and remote devs (though there are other ways to sync plugins, I know).

Comment: This might also be useful in installs where the hosting provider does not provide or allow wp-cli.

Answer (score 2):

## Simple bash script to find your WordPress root

Ever need to run a script outside of WordPress and need to know the WordPress root directory?

```
while [ ! -e wp-config.php ]; do
  if [ $pwd/ = / ]; then
    echo "No WordPress root found" >&2; exit 1
  fi
  cd ../
done
if [ -e wp-config.php ]; then
  wproot=$(pwd)
fi
```

### Use cases:

- Custom shell scripts to sync local and remote folders and databases.
- Docker workflows where wp-cli `wp` commands won't work.
- Webpack/Grunt workflows where you might be issuing commands from the theme folder instead of the WordPress root.

### How to use

- put this code at the top of any script like `myscript.sh`.
- set permissions with `chmod u+x myscript.sh`.
- Use `${wproot}` as a variable in any path.

  - Example `echo "Uploads path is ${wproot}/wp-content/uploads"`.

### Caveats

This is a simple script and may not work under all conditions. It will not work if:

- your wp-config.php file is not stored in your WordPress root
- your wp-config.php file is rename

Admittedly the conditions under which you might need this are pretty rare. I needed it for a visual regression test script that needs to traverse several folders and issue various commands, all without wp-cli or WordPress functions.

Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: Note that the `wp-config.php` file can be one level up, in which case this will generate the wrong result

Comment: Yup, I added to that the Caveats section at the bottom. Is there any other file or folder that is guaranteed to be at wp root? I could search for that instead.